# Java closing Statement

Tags: sql, jdbc, execute

I am not sure, which method is better?

```
con.createStatement().execute("...");
```

OR

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.execute("...");
st.close();
```

When using the first method, will be the statement create closed or it will remain open? I am sure that in the second method the statement will be closed, but in the first one? Anybody know?

Comment: There is no ResultSet in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `con.createStatement().execute("...");` and `Statement st = con.createStatement();` make same sense. However closing the statement is not performed with the first method. Closing the `ResultSet` or `Statement` is a good practice. You may get additional problems with not closed `Statements`. You can close the `Connection` instead, but it's not possible when using a connection pool. Additionally the second method is very useful when using the `PrepairedStatement`, because it can set parameters to the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I strongly disagree. You should always close a statement when you are done with, in that regard `con.createStatement().execute("...");` is clearly inferior as you no longer have a handle to close the statement.

Comment: I agree, however most of primary developers are not close statements. however they can perform their tasks without closing statement. but they getting problems later when the program become bigger. but simple programs not getting problem with non closed statements.

Comment: It is better to unlearn bad behavior/practices at an early stage, than to have it deeply embedded in the way you work and then having to unlearn them.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is good, although the second alternative is better than the first. You should always close a statement when you are done with (not sooner, but definitely not never). Your second alternative attempts to close the statement, but will actually fail to do that if `execute` throws an exception.

To have a guaranteed close of your statement, you can use [try-with-resourc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)e (introduced in Java 7):

```
try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement) {
    statement.execute();
    // Other things you want to with statement...
}
```

If you are unfortunate to be stuck on Java 6 or earlier, you need to use a try/finally:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
try {
    statement.execute();
    // Other things you want to with statement...
} finally {
    statement.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not explicitly close the `Statement` object then it will remain open, at least initially.  It *might* be closed some time after the garbage collector determines that it is unreachable, if ever that happens.  It *will* be closed when the connection is closed, if at that time it is still open.

The best form is usually:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();

try {
    // ...
    st.execute("...");
    // ...
} finally {
    st.close();
}
```

By starting a `try` block immediately after creating a statement, you can be sure that the statement will be closed (in the `finally` block) before it goes out of scope -- even if an arbitrary exception is thrown somewhere within.

Comment: Or, with Java 7+, [try with resources](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_try_with_resources_with) would be a tidier alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippets, you are not explicitly closing the statement, so you can not rely on it being closed. Some driver's implementations call `close()` in the statement's `finalize()` method, but you should not rely on this, and should always explicitly close your statements.